# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined at SVGPathElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have an svg map image and I want to loop over it's path element and add add a class. I get the above error nonetheless. Here is my code

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
svg = document.getElementsByTagName('path');        

for(i=0; i<svg.length;i++)
  {
    svg[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
        svg[i].setAttribute('class','svgclass');
    });
  }

});
```

WHat am i doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: `svg[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){ console.log(i);`

Answer (score 2):

`svg[i]` is undefined at the point `mouseover` occurs. Probably because `i` is equal to the highest value of the loop in every event handler, and at least one of the elements has been removed from the collection.

A better alternative would be to use `this` to reference the element which raised the event instead. Note the use of `classList.add()` as well; this will append a class to any existing ones instead of removing all existing.

```
for (i = 0; i < svg.length; i++) {
  svg[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    this.classList.add('svgclass');
  });
}
```

Comment: Am trying to call it in the console of my browser without the function around it. This time i get the following error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '37' of undefined
    at SVGPathElement'